# Stop/Exit Timer

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to exit out of the Timer below after 5 seconds has past.

I tried `workoutTimer.Stop();`but get the message that 'workoutTimer' does not exist in the context.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

```
var i = 0;
var workoutTimer = new Timer((o) => {
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
        i = i+1;
        if (if i == 5){
            Console.WriteLine('Exit Timer here');
            //workoutTimer.Stop();
        }
    });
}, null, 1000, 1000);
```

Comment: If you are using Xamarin.Forms I would suggest use of [Device.Timer](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer(System.TimeSpan,System.Func%7BSystem.Boolean%7D)/) instead of System timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried calling `Dispose()` and creating a private Timer variable like this:

```
Timer workoutTimer;
void TimerMethod () {
    var i = 0;
    workoutTimer = new Timer (o =>  {Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() =>  {
        i = i + 1;
        if (i == 5) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Exit Timer here");
            workoutTimer.Dispose ();
        }
        Console.WriteLine ("tick");
    });
    }, null, 1000, 1000);
}
```